# Want to make large text align to right

Tags: html, text, web, alignment

I have a weebly website and I am changing the HTML to get some large text into the top right corner.

```
<div style="text-align: right;">Call today! +61 123 456 789</div>
```

^ that is the code

I need to make that quite bigger than what it usually is.
Visit sydneyentertainmentservices.com to see what size it is now.

Unfortunately this website wont let me show you the real size but it looks like this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_font_size that size just a nice font please. HTML!

In a modern font please

Comment: Also Weebly reacts to <h1> and <p> sometimes it just makes it bold

Answer (score 0):

Use the `font-size` property on the div element. Change the size based on how large you want the text to be.

[Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size)

Example:

```html
<div style="text-align: right; font-size:30px;">Call today! +61 123 456 789</div>
```